# Photo-conductivity of n and p type semiconductors

Tags: semiconductors

> Both n-type and p-type semiconductors are available to fabricate a
>   photoconductive devices. To achieve the highest photoconductivity, do
>   you want to use n-type or p-type? Why?

$$σ_{ph}=q(μ_n ∆n+μ_p ∆p);\ \ \ Where\ \mu_n>\mu_p$$

The answer is supposedly p-type but wouldn't the mobility of an electron be higher in a n-type semiconductor than in a p-type semiconductor? Which would mean photoconductivity of a n-type semiconductor would be more?

Comment: Assuming for now you are NOT talking about diode-photoconduction but simple extrinsic photoconduction, have you considered what differences exist between these two situations from the point of view of a photon?

Comment: I dont think it matters n-type vs p-type if they have the same dopant concentration. But that equation doesnt look right to me. Thats not just photoconductivity, thats total conductivity, although maybe thats how your reference defines it? I would have expected only the photogenerated carriers to be counted for photoconductance, not total n and p concentrations. (But there are two big spaces in the equation. Maybe something isnt rendering right on my phone)

Comment: @Matt There are significant differences in the two situations from the perspective of photon-generated interactions in the lattice. n-type drives up the Fermi level of the lattice and sets up a very small (tens of milli-eV) difference between donors and the conduction level, while p-type drives down the Fermi level and sets up very small (tens of milli-eV) difference between acceptors and the valence level. It's actually quite a difference from the photon perspective and from the point of view of the ratio between recombination time and transit time of the conduction band electrons.

Comment: To the OP: google up terms like trapping and detrapping, for example. Also consider what happens to any material that has a lot (great excess) of conduction band electrons present (n-type) when photon flux arrives into that veritable sea of free charges floating about as compared to the case for p-type materials where there are almost no conduction band charges present. There are actually several (not one) mechanisms to be considering here. (In my lay opinion, of course. I've never considered the question before.)

Comment: @jonk I think your analysis is at a higher level than the question is expecting. At an intro level you would just assume that every incident photon generates an e-h pair, no matter the doping situation.

Comment: @matt But the question is specifically pointed at the differences between n- and p- type extrinsic materials. I don't see how to avoid the points I made. If you use a model that ignores them, then I don't think you can see a difference and then you don't have an answer. But what the heck. I'm just a hobbyist. What do I know?

Answer (score 1):

There are minority and majority carrier devices, eg. transistor is majority and hence n-type carriers define properties of devices.
In Photodiodes - dark current depend on minority carriers.

Photo carriers induced by light generate both N and P carriers, and they are spatially "bound" together by electric forces due to opposite charging = ambipolar mobility. Without junction which separate carriers, in uniform material change due to induced light = photocarriers spread like waves..

Looking at device level, you measure not photoconductivity, but its change.

Please look into ambipolar mobility term.